# RDP auto log off for specified user

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I need to set auto log off when user disconnect from rdp. But I need to set this only for one user. All other users should stay logged on when disconnected. Running Win Server 2008 R2....
Any help ??

Comment: Group Policy Security Filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the same answer i posted here:
[Automatically log off idle Terminal Services users without using idle session limits?](https://serverfault.com/questions/369858/automatically-log-off-idle-terminal-services-users-without-using-idle-session-li/376037#376037)

You can go:

- Old cmd/bat school: quser or qwinsta to catch session and use logoff with args to force logoff
- Use Powershell, for example using this library: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSTerminalServices

Answer (score 0):

If your Terminal Server is set up to respect the session limits defined on user objects in Active Directory, then all you need to do is modify the "Sessions" settings on the user object using `Active Directory Users and Computers`. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754128.aspx

But if you're already enforcing session limits, then you will need to use GPO security filtering as @joeqwerty said. You would create a second GPO just for the single user, then set up the filtering so it only applied to that user, and use it to override the settings in the general policy.